# Lock aquisition and transaction order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, locking

In SQL Server, what is the lock acquisition order? How is it decided which transaction is run first?

I know that this is a wide topic, so link to relevant material would be useful.

My experiment (code below) shows, that transaction-2 (lock all rows), waits also for transaction-3, which started later.

Originally, I thought, that there is some kind of FIFO principal for which transactions gets to run.
But now it seems that transactions locking many rows, could wait for very very long time.
(or maybe page/table locks act differently)

```
-- I ran 3 transactions in parallel

-- transaction1 - lock ONE row
BEGIN TRAN PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT * FROM mytable WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE id = 58;
PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME(); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
COMMIT TRAN

-- transaction2 - lock ALL rows
BEGIN TRAN
PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT * FROM mytable WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)
 PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME(); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
COMMIT TRAN

-- transaction3 - lock ONE row
BEGIN TRAN
PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
SELECT * FROM mytable WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE id = 201;
PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME(); WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
COMMIT TRAN


-- Results were:

-- transaction1
2022-04-22 13:16:49.0830498
2022-04-22 13:16:49.0830498
2022-04-22 13:16:54.0941580

-- transaction2
2022-04-22 13:16:49.6759131
2022-04-22 13:16:55.5587416
2022-04-22 13:17:00.5708426

-- transaction3
2022-04-22 13:16:50.5450067
2022-04-22 13:16:50.5450067
2022-04-22 13:16:55.5587416
```

Comment: In short the reason your query with the lock on all rows took longer was because it couldn't gain a lock on the row with an `id` of `58`; so it had to wait as it started after (by .6 seconds). The 3rd transaction, however, wasn't stopped from locking the row with an `id` of `201` so it could run immediately. This meant that "transaction 2" then had to wait for both "transaction 1" and "transaction 3" to complete. Someone far more knowledgable than I will likely to able to explain that with citation much better than I could.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction 2 did not lock all rows; only rows that were touched before the query was blocked were locked.

Note the Transaction 2 scan was blocked by transaction1 when it reached key 58. Keys higher than 58 were not yet accessed by the scan so there was no conflict when  transaction 3 read key 201.

This explanation assumes `id` is an incremental identity column primary key.